# Android - Check internet connection by pinging url address

Tags: java, android, server, ping

I need a service in the background that constantly pings google. But I have no idea how to do it. I am new here. My method does not work does not repeat. It only works once  and it always returns "false" .

**isConnectedToServer function**

```
 public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
try{
  URL myUrl = new URL(url);
  URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
  connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
  connection.connect();
  return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Handle your exceptions
  return false;
}}
```

**onCreate**

```
     @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 if(isConnectedToServer("http://www.google.com",3000)){
      Toast.makeText(this, "Okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
      Toast.makeText(this, "Not Okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I see Not Okay once on the screen. Only once. Even when I have an internet connection. What can I do about it?

Comment: First thing you can do is print the error log from your try catch, might give you a hint. You may need the internet permission too.

Comment: Please update Log exception on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this create a class that extends AsyncTask

```
public class CheckInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
 private static final String TAG = "CheckInternet";
private Context context;


public CheckInternet(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    assert cm != null;
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnected();

    if (isConnected) {
        if ( executeCommand()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean executeCommand(){
    System.out.println("executeCommand");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try
    {
        Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c "+"www.google.com");
        int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
        System.out.println(" mExitValue "+mExitValue);
        if(mExitValue==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignore)
    {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:"+ignore);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'HelperMethods' , Constants 'Interface expected here' getting these errors. I also can't see the codes inside www.google.com. I need to ping google.

Comment: Try now. I have updated the code. In the helper class, I have created the sharedpreferences method. I have removed it

Answer (score 0):

using [icmp4a library](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) for Android (my library) is much better then invoking `ping` command with Runtime process builder.

Example:

1. **Get the library**

```
implementation "com.marsounjan:icmp4a:1.0.0"
```

2. **Single ICMP Ping**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  val status = icmp.ping( host = "8.8.8.8")
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:22:48.515 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 12 ms
```

3. **Multiple ICMP Pings with specified interval**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  icmp.pingInterval(
      "8.8.8.8",
      count = 5,
      intervalMillis = 1000
  )
    .onEach { status ->
        val result = status.result
        when (result) {
          is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
          is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
        }
    }
      .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:29:16.633 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:17.577 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:18.598 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:19.614 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:20.630 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 13 ms
```